# Set all values to one variable in c#

Tags: c#, variables, request, assign

I have a foreach statement that outputs a list of customer id's to a log file:

```
foreach(var customer in _response.CustomersList)
{
      log.WriteLine(customer.CustID);
}
```

The Id's output correctly but the problem I have is I am not able to put them into one variable use them.

For example I wanted to give this request: `_request2.CustID = customer.CustID` but this is not correct.

I need those ID's because I have a cancel customer request:

```
            public void Cancel()
            {
                _request2 = new CancelCust();
                _request2.CommandUser = _request.CommandUser;      
                _request2.CustID = "This is where I would put the variable that holds the customer ID's"         
                _request2.Company = _request.Company;      
            }
```

So, how do I assign those id's to a variable to be used in my request later?

Comment: Do you mean you need to track all the id's (rather than a specific one). Could you not create a list of ints and add each id to it. This is even easier with LINQ but you wouldn't get the logging.

Comment: @JRoughan, yes instead of saying `custid[0] = _response.Customers[0].CustID;` I would input all the Id's at once so that I could cancel them all at once.

Comment: What type of property is Request.CustID? If it's not a collection you'll need to send a different request for each customer.

Comment: I was having a hard time getting this because it is going to be an unknown amount of ID's depending on the company name I request.

Comment: request.company was another request made from the search request. that doesn't need to change I am just keeping it the same as the other request.

Comment: I've added an answer to gather all the customer Ids into a collection, but I don't think that will help. No one can help you unless you tell us what type of property Request.CustId is.

Comment: That's a bit rough... I go through the comments to determine exactly what you need, and you accept an identical answer from someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to accomplish with the code above. BUT, you could use a bit of [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) and get a list of the IDs, then pass around that list as you like:

```
var customerIDs = _response.CustomersList.Select(customer => customer.CustID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the customer Ids by storing them as you go:

```
var customerIds = new List<int>();
foreach (var customer in _response.CustomersList)
{
    customerIds.Add(customer.CustId);
    log.WriteLine(customer.CustID);
}
```

or by using LINQ

```
var customerIds = _response.CustomersList.Select(c => c.CustId);
```

As I pointed out in my comment, if the property Request.CustId is not a collection this won't help you request all of them at once. Are you able to change the definition of Request?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your variable `_request2.CustID` is the wrong type. What error message are you getting from the compiler? (Or, is it a run-time error that you get?)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public void Cancel()
{
    foreach(var customer in _response.CustomersList)
    {
        _request2 = new CancelCust();
        _request2.CommandUser = _request.CommandUser;      
        _request2.CustID = customer.CustID;         
        _request2.Company = _request.Company;      
    }
}
```